# Reactive REST API response filtering based on user roles

Tags: java, spring-webflux, jackson-databind

Is there any reactive JSON response filtering way based on user roles beside blocking one - usage of jackson-databind with @JsonFilter annotation for Pojos and overridden  SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAsField?

Example of blocking property filtering:

SecureFieldFilter.class:

```
public class SecureFieldFilter extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {

    @Override
    public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider, PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {

        SecureField secureField = writer.findAnnotation(SecureField.class);

        //TODO: Get user authorities from ReactiveSpringSecurityContext
        //TODO: Filter properties which not mention particular roles in SecureField annotation
        }
    }
}
```

SecureField annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SecureField {

    UserAuthority[] value();

}
```

SecureFieldFilterConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class SecureFieldFilterConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer addFieldFilters() {
        return jacksonObjectMapperBuilder -> {
            jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.filters(new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("securityFilter", new SecureFieldFilter()));
        };
    }

}
```

Foo.class:

```
@JsonFilter("securityFilter")
public class Banner {

    private UUID id;

    @NotNull
    @SecureField(value={UserAuthority.ROLE_AGENT})
    private String field1;

    @NotNull
    @SecureField(value = {UserAuthority.ROLE_PLAYER, UserAuthority.ROLE_AGENT})
    private String field2;

...
}
```

How I can filter some properties based on user roles from REST API response in reactive way?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? If not, then does the above approach works with spring webflux?

Comment: Please refer to this if you are looking for something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68433082/role-based-field-level-access-control-in-spring-boot-rest-api