# Role based field level access control in Spring boot REST API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

I have a Spring boot REST API having GET endpoint which gets the User details from the database.

```
public class User{

    @JsonProperty
    private String userName;
    @JsonProperty
    private String userAge;
    @JsonProperty
    private String userAddress;

}
```

I have 2 users - user1 and user2 with roles 'ADMIN' and 'USER' respectively. My requirement is that the field `userAge` should only be sent in the JSON response to the consumer if the user who is requesting the API has the role 'ADMIN'.

Is there a standard way in Spring boot to achieve field level access control?

Please note - I have already searched for similar questions on Stack overflow, but the answers include solutions which are not a part of Spring boot framework and are older ways of achieving it. I am specifically looking a standard way to achieve this using Spring boot.

Comment: Boot introduces no differences in the way that you would assert these restrictions.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Which means we need to implement a custom implementation to ignore the fields based on role.

Comment: Don't we have a provision in spring security as well for the same?

Comment: Spring Boot makes Spring Security's core configuration easier to set up. Specific applications (like filtering projections) are the same as if you didn't use Boot and configured your Spring application by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answers your question.

The first thing that comes to mind, is using Jackson @JsonViews,

In shorts

> Most of the time we come across requirements in an application where we want to provide different views of the same model data to different clients/users.
>
> To solve this, we may end up creating multiple models/DTOs to
> represent different views of the same state to different clients. For
> models with a limited number of fields this approach may work, but for
> large models, it will become difficult to manage and will result in
> duplication of code.

So you define two different views, one for `ADMIN` and one for `USER` and then you have two options, in which the first one fits your question perfectly.

1- Serialize and Deserialize based on condition checking, you can get the `user` from application security context, check for role and deserialize based on the right `View`.

2- Create different endpoints for `ADMIN`, `USER` and simply use `annotation` driven development to return the view you require with out doing the role check.

Both options are natively supported, but I recommend using the first option for encapsulating the APIs.

This article covers both options, please take a look at it and see if it matches your use case, I sure hope it does.

Reference: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/jackson-jsonview-its-meaningful-use-spring-boot-rest-amit-patil/